# implementation issue on @OneToMany relationship recursive call infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've two classes city and religious places where a city can have multiple religious places, but a religious place can have only one city, but when I implement as per requirement I got an error my response stuck in the recursive call.

I am expecting response of all religious places which is located in requested city

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want any body to help you, then first show your efforts in solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may tell Jackson to disregard certain data during serialisation by adding @JsonIgnore to the religious places field in the City class and the city field in the ReligiousPlace class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "religious_places")
class ReligiousPlace {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private City city;
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "city")   
class City {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ReligiousPlace> religious_places;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you sir, it's really worked for me a lot I was stuck so much because of recursive error your response helped me a lot to remove that recursive and my calls are working properly now**